# Обособление приложений

Tags: приложение

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Столица, Мехико-Сити, — самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей,   расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

Мой вариант - это два тире без запятых или наоборот без тире...

Столица, Мехико-Сити — самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей —  расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

Или:

Столица, Мехико-Сити, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей,   расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Столица, Мехико-Сити — самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей  —  расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

Столица, Мехико-Сити, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей, расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

**Приложения, носящий характер уточнения, могут отделяться с двух сторон тире.**

Answer (score 1):

(1) Мехико-Сити, столица, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей, расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

(2) Мехико-Сити, столица - самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей, - расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

(3) Мехико-Сити, - столица, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей, - расположен на высоте почти двух километров над уровнем океана, и самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой.

**Согласование делается с подлежащим** (Мехико-Сити), топоним относится к  м.р. по родовому слову "город".

**Пример с тире** (перенос второй запятой): Все мы, воспитатели – учителя и вожатые, – должны много работать с детьми.

**Дополнение**

**Вообще говоря, наилучший вариант - это первый, с одними запятыми.** Он простой, не вычурный,  и притом вполне информативный. Там нет конфликта двух родов (город и столица). Можно также заметить,  что использование одного или двух тире в середине предложения чаще всего искажает его графику, затрудняет прочтение, поэтому эти знаки лучше использовать там, где они действительно необходимы.

Comment: В последнем вашем примере два приложения:одно поясняет другое. А в нашем примере тоже два приложения?

Comment: В примере (2) второе приложение дополняет первое, а  в  примере (3) два независимых приложения.

Comment: Да, понятно. ...

Answer (score 0):

> **Столица**, Мехико-Сити, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами
>   жителей, **расположен** на высоте...

*...расположен**а**  на высоте...*

.

Думаю, возможен и такой вариант:

***Столица — Мехико-Сити, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей — расположена на высоте...***

**И ещё...**

Не уверен в том, что Мехико-Сити по состоянию на 2016 год действительно *"самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей"*. См.:

[***Опубликован доклад Demographia World Urban Areas за 2015 год. В нем немало любопытных сведений о быстро меняющейся демографической ситуации на планете...***](http://culturavrn.ru/world/16907)

**И ещё** -- по поводу *"расположен на высоте **почти** двух километров над уровнем океана".*

Почему ***"почти"?*** Раньше ведь Мехико располагался на высоте ***более*** 2000 м над уровнем моря.  Вряд ли он сейчас спустился…

**И ещё…**

Всё предложение, по-моему, лучше переработать. Может быть, разбить на два предложения, что-то добавить... Уж больно непонятно (на **мой** взгляд) смотрится союз "и" вот здесь: *"**и** самолет долго летит над ним перед неожиданно быстрой посадкой"*. Ничего о протяжённости города перед этим "и" ведь не было сказано: речь шла только о высоте...

Comment: slava1947, а почему? Мехико-сити - он. Я бы тоже, пишучи что-то подобное, согласовал бы со столицей, но отказывать в праве согласования с названием не могу. "Столица" здесь не родовое слово.

Answer (score 0):

> Мой вариант - это два тире без запятых или наоборот без тире...

Надо уточнить у автора, зачем он обособляет "Мехико-Сити".

Вот я сконструировал фразу, где подобная пунктуация совсем не кажется дикой.
*Третий сын, Иван, - самый дурной из всех - пустил стрелу на болото...*

Да, и тут можно сомневаться, но пунктуация вполне мотивирована. Но и в этом случае запятая между "всех" и "пустил" не нужна. Равно как необъяснима она и между "жителей" и "расположен".

Короче, если нет возможности уяснить, зачем обособление и что у автора главное, "Столица" или "Мехико", взял бы вариант slava1947, включая согласование со "столицей".

А так - есть масса вариантов.

И этот не самый безнадежный:

*Столица, Мехико-Сити, — самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей - расположена на высоте*

или

*Столица - Мехико-Сити, самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей, расположен на высоте...*

Вот вариант Сержа мне не нравится, там что-то с синтаксисом то ли структуры предложения (что чему приложение и какое слово главное), то ли с родом сказуемого, что slava1947 тоже подметил.

Comment: Меня тут осенило: _Столица, Мехико-Сити — самый населенный город мира с 30 миллионами жителей, который  расположен..._ И род сказуемого сохраняется...

Comment: А Ваш вариант с тире после столицы позволяет сохранить род по причине, что все обороты теперь поясняют слово _"столица"_? А родовое слово - это теперь Мехико-Сити? Не очень понимаю... Хотя вариант нравится.